# Multiple Dependency Injection using Ninject

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject

I am trying to do multiple dependency injection using Ninject.
I have 3 classes, `EmailHelper`, `ExceptionHelper` and `ReportHelper`.
`ExceptionHelper` class requires `EmailHelper` and `ReportHelper` requires `ExceptionHelper`. Here is my code.

```
IKernel _kernel = new StandardKernel();
_kernel.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

IEmailHelper _emailHelper = _kernel.Get<IEmailHelper>(); 

ExceptionHelper exceptionHelper = new ExceptionHelper(_emailHelper);
ReportHelper reportHelper       = new ReportHelper(exceptionHelper);
```

`ExceptionHelper` and `IEmailHelper` seems loosely coupled, but `ReportHelper` and `ExceptionHelper` are still tightly coupled.

How can I make `ReportHelper` and `ExceptionHelper` loosely coupled?

Can I modify my code like this ?

```
IExceptionHelper _exceptionHelper = _kernel.Get<IExceptionHelper>();
ReportHelper reportHelper = new ReportHelper(_exceptionHelper);
```

But `IExceptionHelper` is not initiated with `IEmailHelper`?
I am confused.

[edited]

Here is my `ExceptionHelper` constructor. Rest constructor has same structure.

```
private IEmailHelper _emailHelper;
public ExceptionHelper(IEmailHelper eh)
{
    _emailHelper = eh;
}
```

Comment: Create corresponding interfaces for each.

Comment: @DavidL I already made interfaces for each class.

Comment: Can you include the constructors of those classes in your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constructors of your classes should look like something like this:

```
public ExceptionHelper(IEmailHelper email_helper)
{
    m_EmailHelper = email_helper;
}

public ReportHelper(IExceptionHelper exception_helper)
{
    m_ExceptionHelper = exception_helper;
}
```

Then you need to make sure that all of your types are registered with the container like this (or use other automatic ways of registration):

```
kernel.Bind<IReportHelper>().To<ReportHelper>();
kernel.Bind<IExceptionHelper>().To<ExceptionHelper>();
kernel.Bind<IEmailHelper>().To<EmailHelper>();
```

Then you can build a `IReportHelper` instance like this:

```
IReportHelper report_helper = kernel.Get<IReportHelper>();
```

And the container will manage the wiring automatically.

Comment: I don't understand `IReportHelper report_helper = kernel.Get<IReportHelper>()` this part. I don't need to pass `IExceptionHelper` instance as parameter?

Comment: Yes. The DI container will detect that the constructor of `ReportHelper` requires a `IExceptionHelper` dependency and it will be able to inject it. This is called Auto Wiring.